# NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate to update Table Cell after merging changes from another context

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, nsfetchedresultscontroller, restkit

I have a TableViewController that's a `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`. The data that this table is displaying is getting updated in another context (by [RestKit](http://restkit.org)) and getting merged upon notification. At this point if I were to run a query on the main thread's `ManagedObjectContext` I see the data that was updated by the other thread.

When that merge of context happens, the TableViewController, being a `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`, even gets the `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath` message. The issue I'm having is that the object (didChangeObject), still has the old data. I imagine this is so because whatever is calling this message just uses the current `NSFetchResultsController` to give me that object.

Why didn't the `NSFetchResultsController`'s fetchObjects get updated from the context merge? Is there a way to have fetchObjects be updated by the context merge and perform this fetch again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was that the merge from changes marks the NSManagedObject's data as being in fault because it's stale. By default staleness interval is set to be infinite apparently. I would give credit to where I found this info but I can't find it now. Anyway, setting the NSManageObjectContext like so allows that context to see the updated info right away.

```
[__managedObjectContext setStalenessInterval:0];
```